# Trying with piping commands into an if statement

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, pipe, sh

I have a bash script that puts a bunch of commands to make a directory into a text file. Then it `cat`s the file into `sh` to run the commands. What I am trying to do is only run the command if the directory doesn't already exist.

Here is what I have:

A text file with something like this:

```
mkdir /path/to/a/directory
mkdir /path/to/another/directory
mkdir /path/to/yet/another/directory
```

In my script I have a line like this

```
cat /path/to/my/file.txt | sh
```

But is there a way to do something like this?

```
cat /path/to/my/file.txt | if path already exists then go to the next, if not | sh
```

In other words I would like to skip the attempt to make the directory if the path already exists.

Comment: can't pipe commands into `if`. Your project sounds overly ambitious. Get a simpler version working and the decide if it is *really* worth the effort to rebuild shell scripting paradigms;-).  The traditional test for dir existence is `if ! [[ -d "$dir" ]] ; then mkdir -p "$dir" ; fi`. Good luck.

Comment: The problem isn't that you can't pipe to an `if` statement (which you can), it's that you really need a loop here.

Comment: @chepner : You *can* pipe to an `if` statement!? Cool, Can you give a 1/2 liner example here as a comment? Thanks

Comment: It's not as exciting as you might think; `if` doesn't use its open file handles, but rather just passes them to any commands contained within it. `somecommand | if [ -f output.txt ]; then cat >> output.txt; else cat > output.txt; fi`. In a world where `>>` won't create a file, this toy example would write or append the command's output to the output file. The `cat` command inherits its standard input from the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear if you want to check for the existence of files or directories.. but here's how to to it:

Run your command if the file exists:

```
[ -f /path/to/my/file.txt ] && cat /path/to/my/file.txt | sh
```

or to check for directories:

```
[ -d /path/to/my/directory ] && cat /path/to/my/file.txt | sh
```

Comment: This is what helped the most. I actually used it as such:

`[ -d /path/to/dir ] || mkdir /path/to/dir`

Again, as mentioned above I am not actually using mkdir, but I was able to incorporate this answer, and I used `||` rather than `&&` since I only wanted it to run if the path did not already exist.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: The OP has since clarified that use of `mkdir` is just an example, and that he needs a *generic* mechanism to conditionally execute lines from a text file containing shell commands, based on whether the commands refers to an existing directory or not:

```
while read -r cmd dir; do [[ -d $dir ]] || eval "$cmd $path"; done < /path/to/my/file.txt
```

- The `while` loop reads the text file containing the shell commands line by line.
- `read -r cmd dir` parses each line into the first token - assumed to be the command (`mkdir` in the sample input) - and the rest, assumed to be the directory path.
- `[[ -d $dir ]]` tests the existence of the directory path, and `||` only executes its RHS if the test *fails*, i.e., if the directory does *not* exist.
- `eval "$cmd $path"` then executes the line; note that use of `eval` here is not any less secure than piping to `sh` - in both cases you must trust the strings representing the commands. (Using `eval` from the current Bash shell means that *Bash* will execute the command, not `sh`, but I'm assuming that's not a problem.)

---

**Original answer, based on the assumption that `mkdir` is actually used:**

The simplest approach in your case is to add the `-p` option to your `mkdir` calls, which will quietly ignore attempts to create a directory that already exists:

```
mkdir -p /path/to/a/directory
mkdir -p /path/to/another/directory
mkdir -p /path/to/yet/another/directory
```

To put it differently: `mkdir -p` ensures existence of the target dir., whether that dir. already exists or has to be created.
(`mkdir -p` can still fail, such as when the target path is a *file* rather than a dir., or if you have insufficient permissions to create the dir.)

You can then simply pass the file to `sh` (no need for `cat` and a pipe, which is less efficient):

```
sh /path/to/my/file.txt
```

In case you do not control creation of the input file, you can use `sed` to insert the `-p` option:

```
sed 's/^mkdir /&-p /' /path/to/my/file.txt | sh
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great to know, but I'm not actually using mkdir, I'm using another script that basically runs as mkdir, but works on our internal network. That script sadly does not have the -p flag, but again this is helpful info for the future!

Comment: @VanCityGuy: I'm glad you found a solution and my answer still helpful. In the future, please state all constraints, as well as which aspects of your sample input are incidental, from the beginning. I've added a generic solution at the top of my answer that hopefully also covers your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own `mkdir` function.

Assuming your file doesn't use `mkdir -p` anywhere this should work.

```
mkdir() {
    for dir; do
        [ -d "$dir" ] || mkdir "$dir"
    done
}
export -f mkdir

sh < file
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but it is a little beyond me. Looks interesting though, I'll have to do some research into writing my own functions, this could be very useful for other projects.

Thanks!